# Set color slider in table view cell to full length of cell

Tags: ios, swift

I am incorporating this [color slider](https://github.com/gizmosachin/ColorSlider) into my app and I am having trouble getting it to fit inside a table view cell so that it takes up the length of the cell in both portrait and landscape view. Below are two screenshots showing my app in portrait and landscape. You can see the color slider does not extend the full length of the cell. Here is my code that sets up the color slider. I am trying to figure out how to property code the CGRect so that the color slider dynamically fills the length of the cell.

```
  func configureColorSlider() {
    let colorSlider = ColorSlider()
    let xCell = colorCell.contentView.bounds.width
    let yCell = colorCell.contentView.bounds.height
    colorSlider.frame = CGRect(x: xCell / 4, y: yCell / 4, width: 200, height: 24)
    colorSlider.orientation = .horizontal
    colorSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ConfigureTimestampTableViewController.changedColor(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    colorCell.contentView.addSubview(colorSlider)
  }
```

Current view in portrait:
[image: Color Slider Portrait]

Current view in landscape:
[image: Color Slide Landscape]

***EDIT (Again)*** 
From your suggestion I updated my code below. This works great in portrait orientation. The color slider takes up the full size of the cell to the right of the color label. However, when I rotate the phone to landscape orientation the color slider only fills half the screen. Below is a screenshot of how it looks.

```
  func configureColorSlider() {
    let colorSlider = ColorSlider()
    let xCell = colorCell.contentView.bounds.width
    let yCell = colorCell.contentView.bounds.height
    colorSlider.frame = CGRect(x: xCell / 4, y: yCell / 4, width: 200, height: 24)
    colorSlider.orientation = .horizontal
    colorSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ConfigureTimestampTableViewController.changedColor(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    colorCell.contentView.addSubview(colorSlider)

    colorSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([colorSlider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
                                 colorSlider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorCell.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
                                 colorSlider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorCell.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
                                 colorSlider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorCell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8) ])


}
```

[image: Landscape Updated Code]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you have set the width of the color slide to 200 so it will always be 200.

You should use auto layout to achive this, you can add constraints in your storyboard/nib file or you if you built the view programticly you can add autolayout using anchores e.g something like this

```
colorSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        colorSlider.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(UILable.leadingAnchor),
        colorSlider.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(cell.trailingAnchor),
        colorSlider.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(cell.topAnchor, constant: 8),
```

colorSlider.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(cell.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
            ])

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but it is crashing my app. Makes sense that I should use auto layout to achieve this. I will keep playing around with the code.

Comment: The code I provided is an example it's hard to give you the code with out seeing your full code. What error are you getting when it crashes. Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I am using storyboards. I just updated my question above with the code I tried from your suggestion. Thank you for the help!

Comment: First thing is you are adding the subview after setting the NSLayoutConstraint, add the subview first

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the desired view working when the phone is in portrait mode. However, in landscape mode the color slider does not extend the full length of the cell. I have updated my edit above to show how it looks. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It hard to say without seeing more of the project, if you could send me it that would be easier other wise try getting rid of the frame code as that is irrelevant now as your setting out the size and position of the colour slider with auto layout.

Comment: Here is the link to the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Marcoc88/TimestampApp). The code in question is in ConfigureTimestampTableViewController.swift